# Removing blank page before eledpar pages

Tags: blank-page, eledpar

[eledpar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eledpar) add one or more blank pages before starting, even with an even number of pages before it. Is it possible to start eledpar pages next to the previous content ?

The following code produce 5 pages : the frontmatter (i), a blank one (ii), a blank page (1), the eledpar left page (2) and the eledpar right page (3). I would expect only 3 pages : the frontmatter (i), the eledpar left page (1) and the eledpar right page (2).

I'm able to remove the blank page (ii) with `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage`, but not the next one.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\blindtext
\mainmatter

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Your main problem is in the combination of \mainmatter, which need clearing two page, and \Pages, which also needs. I open an issue on it. I have a solution, but that will requires you move to reledpar. I will do it this week and ask for test. https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 2.4.0 of reledpar, juste uploaded on CTAN, allows to use `\Pages` with optional argument `mainmatter`, to use instead of `\mainmatter\Pages`.

See the following example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\blindtext


\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}


\end{pages}

\Pages[mainmatter]
\end{document}
```